# Поддержка «местных сообществ» знаниями

Tags: обсуждение

Для начала, что такое «местное сообщество». Местное сообщество - это группа людей объединенных общими интересами, которые территориально находятся в непосредственной близости. В контексте этого определения, к местным сообществам можно отнести:

- группы пользователей технологий (например, [Московское сообщество программистов Django](https://moscowdjango.ru/) или [Санкт-Петербургское сообщество .NET разработчиков](http://spbdotnet.org));
- конференции;
- хакатоны;
- встречи разработчиков.

Дополнительно, к местным сообществам я бы отнес:

- университеты;
- курсы дополнительного образования;
- ИТ-компании.

Так как в подобных организациях часто проводятся бесплатные образовательные мероприятия.

В сообществе Stack Overflow на русском принимают участие большое количество высококвалифицированных разработчиков программного обеспечения, именно поэтому многие программисты выбирают Stack Overflow на русском для обсуждения задач возникающих в повседневной деятельности. Уверен, добродетель участников Stack Overflow на русском простирается далеко за пределы нашего интернет-сообщества. После личных бесед с участниками, мне стало очевидно, что многие пользователи сайта активно выступают с докладами на различных образовательных мероприятиях.

Иногда, так случается, что подобные мероприятия завершаются не успешно, в связи с отсутствием достаточного количество слушателей. С другой стороны, одной из постоянных сложностей местных сообществ является отсутствие докладчиков на встречах. Как мне кажется, мы можем объединить усилия участников Stack Overflow на русском и местных сообществ.

Уверен, учитывая миссию Stack Overflow, компания будет рада поддержать большинство начинаний образовательного характера с участием пользователей сообщества (например, покупка чая и печенок для мероприятий, сувениров и т. д.). Объединив наши усилия с местными сообществами, вместе мы сможем повысить уровень образования среди русскоязычных разработчиков программного обеспечения, что непременно приведет к улучшению в индустрии в целом!

Если у вас есть желание поддержать местные сообщества знаниями, пожалуйста, ответьте на этот вопрос. В ответе укажите:

- где территориально вы бы хотели выступить;
- на какие темы вы бы хотели поговорить;
- на какой основе вы бы хотели выступать (разовая - один доклад, постоянная - курс лекций);
- в каких типах местных сообществ вам бы хотелось читать доклад;
- любую другую информацию (например, ссылки на предыдущие выступления).

Не стесняйтесь публиковать ваши ответы!

*Как предполагается построить процесс?*

Список докладчиков из участников сообщества Stack Overfow на русском будет доступен в этом вопросе на Мете. При необходимости, представители местных сообществ свяжутся через обратную связь с администрацией. Администрация, в свою очередь, напишет заинтересованным участникам. В случае, если у потенциального докладчика будет желание и время принять участие в мероприятии он самостоятельно свяжется с организаторами. На мой взгляд, такой процесс поможет избежать спама и навязчивых предложений.

Таким образом, если вы бы хотели, чтобы один из участников сообщества Stack Overflow на русском выступил с докладом на вашем *образовательном* мероприятии, пожалуйста, напишите мне на почту или воспользуйтесь [формой обратной связи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact). Пожалуйста, связывайтесь исключительно указанными способами. Очень бы не хотелось лишний раз донимать докладчиков.

Если вы хотите, чтобы Stack Overflow поддержала вас или ваше мероприятие, пожалуйста, напишите об этом на почту или воспользуйтесь [формой обратной связи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact).

*Давайте делиться знаниями вместе!*

---

Данный вопрос долгоиграющий. Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь добавлять ваш ответ, если у вас в *данный момент* есть время и желание выступить. Также, не стесняйтесь вносить правку/удалять ответ, в случае изменений в ваших планах.

Время от времени этот вопрос будет отмечаться служебной меткой [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) для привлечения внимания сообщества.

Answer (score 8):

Я буду рад поддержать сообщества в Санкт-Петербурге и Москве. Темы, на которые я могу подготовить доклад.

- Stack Overflow и Stack Overflow на русском!
- Chromium.
- Шаблоны программирования.
- [c#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) в [unity3d](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d).
- Различные темы по запросу по [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) и [golang](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang).
- Программирование в общем.
- Организация команд и процессов в ИТ-компаниях.

Буду рад принять участие в мероприятиях на разовой основе в:

- группах пользователей технологий;
- конференциях, хакатонах и встречах;
- открытых лекциях в университетах;
- открытых лекциях различных курсов дополнительного образования;
- ИТ-компаниях.

Скорее всего, смогу делать не более двух докладов в месяц. Языки докладов: русский, английский.

Answer (score 4):

Я готов делать небольшие доклады и презентации (час, максимум два) по следующим темам:

- Docker и его применение
- Тестирование: виды, грабли, внедрение, плюсы, которые это дает, и как объяснить это менеджеру
- PHP - тестирование, организация идеального приложения, решение стандартных проблем (кеширование, "тяжелые" данные и прочее)
- Правильное разделение работы в команде - как заставить фронтенда и бэкенда работать раздельно
- Общие вопросы по организации разработки веб-приложений - как должен быть организован процесс разработки, зачем нужны тесты, в какой момент приложение должно делиться на модули, почему микросервисы лучше монолита
- Как спасти плохо написанное приложение - что делать, если его внутренности не поддаются рефакторингу
- Оптимизация веб-приложения - профилирование, горизонтальное масштабирование и организация приложения для его поддержки
- Анализ кода: опять-таки тестирование, профилирование, статический анализ, запах кода

Также я могу просто порассказывать common knowledge про какие-либо технологии:

- Тот же Docker
- Vagrant и его применение
- PHP - и почему его уже наконец стоит прекратить пинать
- AMQP
- Redis
- Hibernate и/или его клон Doctrine - и почему большинство других решений и рядом не стоят
- Composer
- Git, Mercurial
- Codeception
- Allure Framework
- Continuous Integration и популярные решения
- Обзор популярных движков БД
- Ведение репозитория приложения (документирование API, миграции)

Мне очень сильно импонирует идея разовых лекций (не докладов - хотелось бы рассказывать не просто кучу клевых названий и общие слова, а какие-то конкретные вещи) по какой-либо теме.