# Презентации StackOverflow на русском в технических вузах вашего города

Tags: обсуждение, встречи-сообщества

Перезагрузка вопроса: [Поддержка «местных сообществ» знаниями](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/883/181472)

Впереди сентябрь, время когда студенты ещё не прогуливают все пары и пока что жаждут знаний.

Может быть, организовать для них презентации, на которых будет рассказано про Ru.SO, плюс к этому пара интересных докладов и сессия вопросов-ответов на ходу?

Не имею конкретного плана мероприятия, просто закидываю идею.

**Вопросы к сообществу:**

- **Стоит ли вообще это делать?**
- **Как сделать это мероприятие интересным?**
- **Как сделать его полезным?**

---

Что это даст студентам:

- Пообщаться с более опытными коллегами
- Приобрести полезные знакомства
- Узнать, как устроен процесс разработки ПО в реальном мире
- Что-нибудь понять насчет пути своего профессионального развития
- Задать вопрос «что лучше, Java или C#?» (чтобы потом не задавать его на SO).
- Понять наконец-то, как правильно задавать вопрос о домашней работе.

Докладчикам:

- Познакомиться с активными участниками SO из своего города
- Можно попиарить себя или свою компанию
- Можно найти перспективного стажера
- Просто хорошее дело

Если рекламный бюджет SO это предусматривает и позволяет, можно самым активным студентам подарить, например, майки, в которых они будут потом ходить как живые рекламные баннеры SO.

Относительно Новосибирска: есть выход на НГУ, прошу заинтересованных отметиться как-нибудь.

Comment: Кстати, надо бы придумать метку, что-то вроде [meta-tag:мероприятия-сообщества],  [meta-tag:проекты-сообщества] или  [meta-tag:инициативы-сообщества]

Comment: Взаимоисключающие параграфы, в нормальном ГТУ итак все знают без всяких SO. Интернет это ведь порождение научного сообщества, а не наоборот.

Comment: @igumnov, а что именно взаимоисключающе? к слову: научное сообщество вряд ли возможно без механизмов сохранения и обмена знаниями, а интернет вообще и ru.so в частности — один из множества таких механизмов.

Comment: Приезжайте читать лекцию в НГУ, я постараюсь прийти :-)

Comment: @TagirValeev я? Может, наоборот? ) Мне пока не о чем рассказывать)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я в Питере на Joker'е буду бубнить доклад, заглядывайте ;-)

Comment: Это только по России?!

Comment: @AslanKussein: поскольку это организует не Stack Exchange, а энтузиасты из числа сообщества SO, то организовать можно где угодно, где соберется достаточное число этих энтузиастов. Соберете в своем городе — будет и в нем.

Comment: @TagirValeev: может, расскажете про внутренности JVM или что-нибудь такое же хардкорное и интересное? https://plus.google.com/117414439764242603546/posts/GnrucegS9tE

Comment: @NickVolynkin, пока ничего обещать не могу. Сильно много всяких дел. Хороший доклад подготовить — много времени нужно.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На наш взгляд, проводить такие мероприятия стоит. Stack Exchange бы их с радостью всевозможно поддержала: от раздаточного материала (футболки, ручки, блокноты) до печенек и чая! Вопрос здесь скорее организационного характера. По своему опыту могу судить, что не так просто договориться с представителями университетов и собрать студентов в назначенное время.

Если вы все такие решитесь, пожалуйста, напишите, будем рады помочь всем, чем сможем!

Однажды, у нас был [опыт](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/05/blog-post_28.html) выступления в Петербургском ЛЭТИ. Спешу им поделиться.

- Изначально мероприятие планировалось как "ответы знатоков" - мы анонсировали событие предложив студентам подготовить и задать любой интересующий их вопрос по любой современной технологии. Для ответов на вопросы я пригласил своих товарищей, которые работали с самыми разными технологиями. Общее количество вопросов от студентов составило *ровно ноль*.
- Как нам кажется, формат ответов на технические вопросы больше подходит для написания, чем устного обсуждения. Проблемы, описываемые в вопросах на Stack Overflow на русском, по большей части возникают во время написания кода, а не на лекции в аудитории. Как результат, во время живого общения задать реальный технический прикладной вопрос очень тяжело, даже для опытного разработчика.
- Ожидая низкую активность со стороны студентов, мы заблаговременно подготовили план «Б», в котором предлагали ребятам взглянуть на «типичные» ошибки и «трюки» при написании кода на различных языках. Уже в ответ на серию докладов с примерами у студентов начали появляться вопросы, причем не только по теме доклада.
- Студенты - достаточно необычная аудитория. Среди учащихся ВУЗов могут встречаться как «крепкие» разрабочики, так и те, кто только делает первые шаги. Со своей стороны, мы спешим порекомендовать внимательно ознакомиться с будущей аудиторией, ее знаниями и интересами.
- Самое главное подобных мероприятий - приятно провести время. Зачастую, наиболее интересные вопросы задаются после доклада за чаем.

Хотелось бы подчеркнуть, что практически любая техническая встреча крайне полезна! Человек обладает эмпатией. Как мне кажется, видя перед собой пример знающего разработчика, начинающий программист с большей силой начинает тянуться к знаниям.