# Проба пера – реклама в сообществе от сообществ

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Для контекста, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на публикацию «[Реклама сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2610/)».

---

На наш взгляд, одним из важнейших направлений в развитии русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков как такового являются встречи в реальной жизни <sub>(далее просто встречи)</sub>. Stack Overflow, как и многие другие программные продукты, призван автоматизировать процессы, происходящие в реальности, а именно сбор, каталогизацию и кристаллизацию знаний – решений прикладных задач. Для многих не секрет, что исходная версия Stack Overflow на русском была запущена именно для возможности сбора знаний в одном месте и возможности поделиться находками с коллегами после длительного изучения и решения задач в переговорках и после работы – то есть встреч энтузиастов программирования.

Отнюдь не последняя, с идеологической точки зрения, цель Stack Overflow – показать ребятам, нашим коллегам, что работа программиста – это не зарплата раз в месяц, программирование – это искусство, искусство, к которому приобщается каждый из нас. Сегодня, как мне кажется, русскоязычное сообщество разработчиков «беднее» своих англоязычных коллег. Под «бедностью» я, конечно же, имею в виду знания и культуру обмена ими. Мы считаем, что одна из причин этому – закрытость. Начинается все в ВУЗе, где студенты рассматривают будущих коллег не как компаньонов, а как конкурентов, и в дальнейшем создают аналогичное окружение на рабочем месте. Результат – полное отсутствие профессионального общения и обмена опытом! Реалии я испытал на себе, работая в Мотороле инженером, где пытался собраться «клуб знатоков». Из полтысячи сотрудников клуб посещало 3–5 человек.

Если взглянуть на проблему шире, то можно увидеть, что во всем русскоязычном пространстве количество встреч разработчиков, проводимых на некоммерческой основе, исчисляется несколькими десятками. Печально, не правда ли?

#### Что мы можем сделать?

1. **Поддержать встречи личным присутствием**. Как в роли слушателя, так и в [роли докладчика](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/883/).
2. **Обратить внимание коллег на встречи**. Как личными рекомендациями, так и показывая рекламу встреч на Stack Overflow на русском и, по возможности, на английском всем, кто попадает на сайт из поисковика с ограничением показов по местоположению пользователя.
3. **Каким-либо другим образом поддержать встречи, сообщества и группы пользователей**. В Stack Overflow всегда есть чай и печеньки. Мы будем рады поделиться ими с хорошими людьми.

#### Как, примерно, это может выглядеть на Stack Overflow?

1. Как и для [обычных объявлений от сообщества](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) будет опубликован вопрос на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) с меткой [реклама-сообщества](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0), в котором участники смогут предложить сообществу на рассмотрение объявления о встречах.
2. Ответ должен содержать:

   - Название сообщества.
   - Описание сообщества.
   - Контактные данные организаторов и ссылку на сайт мероприятия.
   - Место и время проведения встреч в общем и информацию о следующей встречи, если дата и место уже определены.
   - Ссылку на баннер сообщества размером 300 на 250 пикселов.

   Информацию о сообществе, дату и время проведения встреч, а также темы встреч должны обновляться при необходимости и всегда отражать реальное положение дел. Как мне кажется, было бы здорово, если бы ответ содержал ссылки на учетные записи участников на Stack Overflow (на русском или на английском), которые посещают (планируют посетить) встречу.
3. Встреча или сообщество, о котором публикуется объявление, должно:

   - Быть некоммерческим. Посещение встреч должно быть бесплатным.
   - Соответствовать [одной из популярных тем Stack Overflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags). Встречи должны быть интересны участникам Stack Overflow и посетителям сайта.
   - Минимум два участника встреч должны быть участниками Stack Overflow, один из которых должен иметь минимум 1 000 баллов репутации. Мы не хотим превратить вопрос с объявлениями в помойку – координаторы должны понимать, как работает сайт и его идеологию.

#### Хорошо, что будем делать дальше?

**Сбор данных о встречах**

Перед тем как написать публикацию, я связывался с несколькими координаторами сообществ. Было бы здорово составить более всеобъемлющую картину. Если вы посещаете какие-либо некоммерческие встречи разработчиков, пожалуйста, сообщите организаторам о инициативе. Также вы можете передать контактные данные координаторов встреч [мне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile) любым удобным для вас способом!

**Отзывы и комментарии**

Если у вас есть идеи о том, как улучшить ситуацию, пожалуйста, напишите об этом в ответе к этому вопросу. Возможно, вам кажется, что инициатива бесполезна – не стесняйтесь, напишите и об этом, конечно же, подкрепив ваше утверждение обоснованием.

Comment: BarCamp Krasnodar: https://twitter.com/barcampKRR/status/702810966115880960